# How to get the current user of the system and store to database?

Tags: sql-server

Why the value stored in the database is the username of the SQL Server instead of the username of the system user? How to get the name of current system user?

```
 string Query = "insert into Locate(Locate_LongLatOut, Locate_IC, CreateDate, CreateBy) values('" + this.txtCoordinate.Text + "', '" + this.txtCustomerIC.Text + "', getdate(), USER_NAME()); ";
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CURRENT_USER` instead `USER_NAME()`.

i.e:

```
SELECT CURRENT_USER;
```

Comment: still giving me the username of the SQL Server

Comment: @user11381786 That is the only user the database engine knows. Without any context, there is little anyone else can suggest. Comments like "doesn't work" are not helpful.